# Web Debugging Tool for Android?

Tags: android, debugging, mobile

I'm looking for some convenient way to debug website on Android. Everything I found so far is not convenient at all (including answers on StackOverflow and search results in Google).

I'm looking for something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4zpL4VBbuU#! but I don't have device to test it on. I have Android SDK installed on Windows 7. Any ideas how would I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial about remote debug on Android:
http://www.smartjava.org/content/remote-chrome-debugging-android

Comment: It looks like the thing I'm looking for :) Let me read and test now.

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires actual device as well. There are no such options they mention on SDK version of device.

Comment: I think you can connect to an emulator.

Comment: I don't see [Settings > Advanced > USB Connect] anywhere in emulator or anything like that. How else can I connect?